What was the method for calculating the length of paid holiday for zero-hours workers?
I’m just curious to know how, before the 1st of April, 2024, a zero-hours worker's number of hours of paid leave was calculated. I’ve seen websites that say the Supreme Court decided, in Harpur Trust v. Brazel, that it was unlawful to calculate the length of paid holiday using the ‘percentage method’ (i.e. multiplying the number of hours worked by 0.1207 (12.07%)), but this does not seem to be true.
Is there any case, regulation or statute that explains the method by which the amount of time a zero-hours worker's paid holiday, as provided by the Working Time Regulations 1998, before the amendments that took effect on 01/04/2024, should be calculated?

I read you to be asking what method was used to compute the length of the paid holiday, recognizing that it might not be the same approach that was or is used to compute the compensation that would be paid in lieu. Is that right?

@Jen Yes! That is exactly right. :)

Doesn't paragraph 78 of the Supreme Court judgment answer this question?

@Lag Not to me, sorry. It simply refers, in part i, to how domestic law can be more generous than EU law, so the UK’s implementation of the Working Time Directive, in the form of the WTR 1998, is acceptable. And in part iii, it just seems to set out how to calculate the ‘average week’s pay’.

@BakedAlaska624 Apologies, I was fixated on pay and didn't notice you were asking about holiday days or your exchange with Jen.
